# Get next and previous object from QuerySet by object

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-2.1

I have and `object` and `QuerySet` which contains this object. I need to get **next** and **previous** `object` of this `QuerySet`.

How can I do that?

I could get **next** this way:

```
next = False
for o in QuerySet:
    if next:
        return o
    if o==object:
       next = True
```

but I think it's very slow and unefficient approach on huge `QuerySet`s.

Do you know a better solution?

Comment: Why would you do that/?

Comment: I need to add next and previous buttons to admin change page for one model. But it needs to respect filtering and ordering of changelist.

Comment: Usually you do want to use *pagination* for that.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is a little bit old but I came across this and didn't find very performant solutions, so I hope it may help someone.
There are 2 pretty good solutions I came up with.

The 1st is more elegant although slightly worse-performing. The 2nd is significantly faster, *especially* for larger QuerySets, but it combines using Raw SQL.

They both find previous & next **ids**, but can, of course, be tweaked to retrieve actual object instances.

1st solution:

```
object_ids = list(filtered_objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
current_pos = object_ids.index(my_object.id)
if current_pos < len(object_ids) - 1:
    next_id = object_ids[current_pos + 1]
if current_pos > 0:
    previous_id = object_ids[current_pos - 1]
```

2nd solution:

```
window = {'order_by': ordering_fields}
with_neighbor_objects = filtered_objects.annotate(
    next_id=Window(
        Lead('id'),
        **window
    ),
    previous_id=Window(
        Lag('id'),
        **window
    ),
)
sql, params = with_neighbor_objects.query.sql_with_params()
#  wrap the windowed query with another query using raw SQL, as
#  simply using .filter() will destroy the window, as the query itself will change.
current_object_with_neighbors = next(r for r in filtered_objects.raw(f"""
        SELECT id, previous_id, next_id FROM ({sql}) filtered_objects_table
        WHERE id=%s
    """, [*params, object_id]))

next_id = current_object_with_neighbors.next_id:
previous_id = current_object_with_neighbors.previous_id:
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you.  I used the 1st and it works great.  I added a wrap so that if you are at the end of the list, next_id = object_ids[0] and if you are at the beginning, previous_id = len(object_ids) - 1.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Django QuerySet API` You can try the following:

For Next:

`qs.filter(pk__gt=obj.pk).order_by('pk').first()`

For previous:

`qs.filter(pk__lt=obj.pk).order_by('-pk').first()`

Comment: Thanks Marcell but the base QuerySet doesn't have to be ordered by id. It can be ordered by anything.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that is what you need (in Python 3, if you need a solution for Python 2.7, let me know):

```
def get_next(queryset, obj):
    it = iter(queryset)
    while obj is not next(it):
        pass
    try:
        return next(it)
    except StopIteraction:
        return None

def get_prev(queryset, obj):
    prev = None
    for o in queryset:
        if o is obj:
            break
        prev = obj
    return prev
```

But there are some notes:

1. As far as full queryset is stored into the variable, you can keep an index of your object and extract next and previous ones as `[i + 1]` and `[i - 1]`. Otherwise you have to go through whole `queryset` to find your object there.
2. According to PEP8 you shouldn't name variables like `QuerySet`, such names should be used for classes. Name it `queryset`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like that:

```
def get_prev_next(obj, qset):
    assert obj in qset
    qset = list(qset)
    obj_index = qset.index(obj)
    try:
        previous = qset[obj_index-1]
    except IndexError:
        previous = None    
    try:
        next = qset[obj_index+1]
    except IndexError:
        next = None
    return previous,next
```

It's not very beautiful, but it should work...